# Wagtial: within StructBlock, pass parameters to child block

Tags: python, wagtail

I have a simple sub-class of `StructBlock`:

```py
class IntegerRangeBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    from_ = blocks.IntegerBlock(label="from")
    to = blocks.IntegerBlock(label="to")
```

For `IntegerBlock`, we can pass `max_value` or `min_value` to it.

Is it possible to do `IntegerRangeBlock(min_value=10)` and give `min_value=10` to `from_`, and `IntegerRangeBlock(max_value=100)` and give `max_value=100` to `to`?

Is there any way to pass parameters to child blocks?

BTW this didnot work:

```py
    def __init__(self, min_value=None, max_value=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.child_blocks["from_"].min_value = min_value
        self.child_blocks["to"].max_value = max_value
```

Comment: did you try to add `def __init__(...)` ? Maybe first check source code for `StructBlock` and [IntegerBlock](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/6395f4bcc13ebb2f3f1ad3487b3b7779b4b34d3e/wagtail/core/blocks/field_block.py#L379)

Comment: @furas Yes I tried that and no luck. Could you please submit an answer with some example code?

Comment: I don't have anwser. I don't even use `wagtail`. I only suggested what I would do to find solution. I dig little in source code but I don't know if this suggestions would work and don't have `wagtail` to test ideas.